# Database Login UserName Password window appeared on view of Crystal report VS2010 with two .ttx file

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on C# 4.0 Win-Form application and using Crystal Report For VS2010. 
In my report i have connection with Field Definition Only File. I have two ".ttx" files.

When I view my report it asks login, UserName and password for second file.
For Example :

I have two ttx files. MastTable.ttx, DetaTable.ttx

Code is as:

```
DataTable A, B;
A.TableName = "MastTable"
B.TableName = "DetaTable"
DataSet D = new DataSet()
D.AddRange(new DataTable[] { A, B } );

MyReport Rep = new MyReport();
Rep.SetDataSource(D);

CrRepViewer.ReportSource = MyReport;
```

Here on view Database login UserName Password window appear for DetaTable.ttx

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. There was nothing wrong with the database. The report was not found. For some reason, if the report is not found, cr ask for a database login.

Comment: Yes, made sure that the cr report file is copied to the folder where the cr viewer tries to load it from. In your solution look at the properties window of your cr report file, it sould be marked as content.

Comment: Will you describe more about Marked as Content.

Comment: I meant the Build Action(in the properties window) for your report file.

Comment: Done, but still problem is as it is.

Comment: Then I would try the preview in the report builder and debug the CrRepViewer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this type of pairing of data tables in my code.

rpt is object of my report.
ds is dataset.

```
rpt.Database.Tables("MastTable").SetDataSource(ds.Tables("MastTable"))
rpt.Database.Tables("DetaTable").SetDataSource(ds.Tables("DetaTable"))
```

if you have sub-reports, then try this,

```
rpt.Subreports(0).Database.Tables("Table1").SetDataSource(ds.Tables("YourTableName"))
```